# Is there a many to many convolution in Pytorch? is this a thing?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have been thinking about convolutions recently. There are common 3by3 convs, where (3,3) kernel's information is weighted and aggregated to supply information to a single spatial point on the output. There are also 3 by 3 upconvs, where a single spatial point on the input supplies weighted information to a 3 by 3 output space.

The conv is a many to one relationship and the upconv is a one to many relationship.

I have however never heard of many to many conv? is there such a thing? For example, a 3by3 kernel supplying information to another 3by3 kernel. I would like to experiment with it in PyTorch. My internet searching has not revealed anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [pixel shuffle](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pixel-shuffle) and averaging to get what you want.
for example, if you want 3x3 -> 3x3 mapping with `in_channels` to `out_channels`:

```py
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as nnf


class ManyToManyConv2d(nn.Module):
  def __init__(in_channels, out_channels, in_kernel, out_kernel):
    self.out_kernel = out_kernel
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channles * out_kernel * out_kernel, in_kernel)

  def forward(self, x):
    y = self.conv(x)  # all the output kernel are "folded" into the channel dim
    y = nnf.pixel_shuffle(y, self.out_kernel)  # "unfold" the out_kernel - image size *out_kernel bigger
    y = nnf.avg_pool2d(y, self.out_kernel)
    return y
```